# lvalue required as left

Tags: c, lvalue

While compiling this code:

```
#define SET_BIT(reg,bitno)          reg|=(1<<bitno)
#define CLR_BIT(reg,bitno)          reg &=~(1<<bitno)
#define GET_BIT(reg,bitno)          ((reg>>bitno)&1)
#define TOGGLE_BIT(reg,bitno)       reg^=(1<<bitno)

switch (PIN_select){

     case DIO_PIN_A:
        if (level==LOW)
            CLR_BIT(DIO_PIN_A,PIN_Bit);
        else if(level==HIGH)
            SET_BIT(DIO_PIN_A,PIN_Bit);
     break;
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment fac(0)=1;
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignmen
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
 #define CLR_BIT(REG,BIT) REG &=~(1<<BIT)
                              ^
 note: in expansion of macro ‘CLR_BIT’
CLR_BIT(DIO_PIN_A,PIN_Bit);
    ^
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
 #define SET_BIT(REG,BIT) REG|=(1<<BIT)
                             ^
```

Answer (score 3):

This line, for example,

```
CLR_BIT(DIO_PIN_A,PIN_Bit);
```

expands to:

```
DIO_PIN_A &= ~(1<<PIN_Bit);
```

However, `DIO_PIN_A` is an integral constant (we know that because it's used in a `case`), so you cannot modify it.